# Java: Identify common paths in ArrayList<String> using Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, substring, frequency

I got an array of elements like :

```
ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList();
t.add("/folder1/sub-folder1");
t.add("/folder2/sub-folder2");
t.add("/folder1/sub-folder1/data");
```

I need to get output as /folder1/sub-folder1 which is mostly repeated path.

In python this can be achieved using the below function:

```
   def getRepeatedPath(self, L):
         """ Returns the highest repeated path/string in a provided list """
         try:
             pkgname = max(g(sorted(L)), key=lambda(x, v): (len(list(v)), -L.index(x)))[0]
             return pkgname.replace("/", ".")
         except:
             return "UNKNOWN"
```

I am trying to work on equivalent lambda function in Java. I got struck and need some help in the lambda implementation.

```
public String mostRepeatedSubString(ArrayList<String> pathArray) {
   Collections.sort(pathArray);
   String mostRepeatedString = null;
    Map<String,Integer> x = pathArray.stream.map(s->s.split("/")).collect(Collectors.toMap()); 
    return mostRepeatedString;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want the most often repeated *maximal, non-root* path, right? Otherwise just `/folder1/*` also occurs twice, and just `/*` occurs 3 times.

Comment: `.map(s->s.split("/"))` returns an array, not "two elements"; there _is_ no no-arg implementation of `Collectors.toMap`.

Comment: @Mshnik : most often repeated  maximal path of maximal length (if root is maximal length then root). In the above case /folder1/sub-folder1 is maximal length than /folder1

Comment: @LouisWasserman:  I agree. But I was trying to split the filenames based on "/" and try out maximum path. Any idea of how we can implement this completely?

Comment: Why is `/folder1/sub-folder1` considered to be the path with “maximal length” when `/folder1/sub-folder1/data` is definitely longer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of tweaking, but I finally got it!

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> t = new ArrayList<String>();
    t.add("folder1/sub-folder1");
    t.add("folder2/sub-folder2");
    t.add("folder1/sub-folder1/data");
    System.out.println(mostRepeatedSubString(t));
  }

  public static String mostRepeatedSubString(List<String> pathArray) {
    return pathArray
      .stream()
      // Split to lists of strings
      .map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("/")))
      // Group by first folder
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(lst -> lst.get(0)))
      // Find the key with the largest list value
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .max((e1, e2) -> e1.getValue().size() - e2.getValue().size())
      // Extract that largest list
      .map(Entry::getValue)
      .orElse(Arrays.asList())
      // Intersect the lists in that list to find maximal matching
      .stream()
      .reduce(YourClassName::commonPrefix)
      // Change back to a string
      .map(lst -> String.join("/", lst))
      .orElse("");
  }

  private static List<String> commonPrefix(List<String> lst1, List<String> lst2) {
    int maxIndex = 0;
    while(maxIndex < Math.min(lst1.size(), lst2.size())&& lst1.get(maxIndex).equals(lst2.get(maxIndex))) {
      maxIndex++;
    }

    return lst1.subList(0, maxIndex);
  }
```

Note that I had to remove the initial `/` from the paths, otherwise that character would have been used in the split, resulting in the first string in every path list being the empty string, which would always be the most common prefix. Shouldn't be too hard to do this in pre-processing though.

Comment: That gave the answer. I am trying to understand more...In the below inputs: is the output folder1  or folder1/sub-folder1 ? t.add("folder1/sub-folder1");
    t.add("folder2/sub-folder2");
    t.add("folder1/sub-folder2/data/hello4");
    t.add("folder2/sub-folder2/data2");
    t.add("folder1/sub-folder1/data/hello");
    t.add("folder1/sub-folder1/data/hello3");

Comment: I removed the initial / from paths too. So that is a valid one.

Comment: Pretty complex with multiple stream() calls :)

Comment: Note that instead of streaming over `Map.entrySet()` and having to call `Map.Entry.getValue()` all the time, you can stream over `Map.values()` in the first place. And don’t abuse `Arrays.asList()`, use `Collections.emptyList()` instead. Though, you don’t need to deal with all these `List`s at all. You are splitting the strings into lists, just to join them at the end. The only place where a `List` feature is used, is the `get(0)` call. But that’s equivalent to `s.substring(0, s.indexOf('/'))` (and implementing a `commonPrefix` for two `String`s intead of `List`s should not be too hard.

Comment: Though, I’m not sure whether considering just the number of occurrences of the first path component is matching the OP’s task description at all. What if I pass in `a/a`,`a/b`,`a/b`? It will print `a` as the common prefix, but I could consider `a/b` as the path with the highest number of occurrences instead (twice than `a/a`). And what about `a/c`,`a/d`,`a/e`, `b/f`, `b/f`? This solution gives precedence to `a`, rather than `b/f`…

Comment: for a/a, a/b, a/b input  : a/b seems most occuring path  and a is most common path.

Comment: Does    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(lst -> lst.get(lst.size() - 2))) makes the difference ?

Comment: to my understanding, in `[a/a, a/b, a/b]`, the most common path is `a/*`, with a cardinality of 3. If that's wrong I'd have to change the answer.

Comment: Ah ok, hm. You may need to specify the desired output of the function, because it's not really clear right now. What happens in `[a/b, a/c, a/d]`? What about `[a/b/c, a/b/d]` ? What about in `[a/, a/b, a/c]`? What about in `[a/b, a/b/, a/c/d, a/c/e, a/c/f]`?

Comment: I think there is a confusion between most common path and most repeated path here. what @Holger said is repeated path and it make sense. In most cases common path used to be root path.  The most repeated item will give us more clear answer.

Comment: [a/b, a/c, a/d] =>  a ,     [a/b/c, a/b/d] => a/b    [a/,a/b, a/c] => a   [a/b,a/b/, a/c/d,a/c/e, a/c/f] = a/c

Comment: .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(lst -> lst.get((lst.size() - 1) / 2))) : This worked fine for above four test cases. The idea is to start grouping from mid of list instead of starting or end of list.